# how to animate the size of the container, as contents within it change in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation

I want to create an animated button, which has a sync icon initially when user taps on it, it will also contain a text "Cancel" and the sync icon starts spinning.

Initial state

[image: initial state]

Final state

[image: final state]

This is widget i am using for button. I know this can be done by adding transition property in CSS, i tried using ScaleTransition in Flutter, but still the container expands abruptly (as ScaleTransition itself takes up all the size in beginning itself).

```dart
AnimatedContainer(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 3000),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.pink.withOpacity(0.6),
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              RotationTransition(
                turns: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0)
                    .animate(_rotationAnimationController),
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.sync,
                  color: Colors.pink,
                ),
              ),
              ScaleTransition(
                scale: _scaleAnimationController,
                child: (state is NoteSyncOnGoing)
                    ? Row(
                        children: const [
                          SizedBox(width: 5),
                          Text(
                            "Cancel",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.pink,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 5),
                        ],
                      )
                    : const SizedBox.shrink(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

**EDIT**

Checking the state before ScaleTransition doesn't solve the issue as well, because when ScaleTransition is mounted, the ScaleTransition widget itself acquires the maximum space acquired by its child after the scaling animation is completed.

So it will result in something like this

[image]

And then Cancel text appears by scaling animation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AnimatedContainer doesn't give you size animation, you have to use AnimatedSize, And remove ScaleTransition.

```
AnimatedSize(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 3000),
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.pink.withOpacity(0.6),
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            RotationTransition(
              turns: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0)
                  .animate(_rotationAnimationController),
              child: const Icon(
                Icons.sync,
                color: Colors.pink,
              ),
            ),
            (state is NoteSyncOnGoing)
                ? Row(
              children: const [
                SizedBox(width: 5),
                Text(
                  "Cancel",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.pink,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 5),
              ],
            )
                : const SizedBox.shrink(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the state inside scale transition check it before the scale transition widget

```
AnimatedContainer(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 3000),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.pink.withOpacity(0.6),
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              RotationTransition(
                turns: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0)
                    .animate(_rotationAnimationController),
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.sync,
                  color: Colors.pink,
                ),
              ),
           (state is NoteSyncOnGoing)?   ScaleTransition(
    scale: _scaleAnimationController,
                child: Row(
                        children: const [
                          SizedBox(width: 5),
                          Text(
                            "Cancel",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.pink,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 5),
                        ],
                      )

              ):SizedBox.shrink(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Checking the state before ScaleTransition doesn't solve the issue as well, because when ScaleTransition is mounted, the ScaleTransition widget itself acquires the maximum space acquired by its child after the scaling animation is completed. 

Please check the image in edit